# How to assign function key (F7) as a shortcut key while making extension for Google Chrome?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I am actually making an extension for Google Chrome and this is only a small snippet of code I wrote for this particular question.Actually, I want to know that how would I make F7 key as the shortcut key.

**manifest.json**

```
{
        "name": "extension",
        "description" : "Base Level Extension",
        "version": "1.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "browser_action": {
            "default_popup" : "hello.html",
            "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
        },
        "commands" : {
            "_execute_browser_action" : {
                "suggested_key" : {
                    "default" : "F7"
                }, 
                "description" : "Opens hello.html"
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Function keys (such as F7) are not available for use as a shortcut.

From [commands](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands) documentation:

> Supported keys: A-Z, 0-9, Comma, Period, Home, End, PageUp, PageDown, Space, Insert, Delete, Arrow keys (Up, Down, Left, Right) and the Media Keys (MediaNextTrack, MediaPlayPause, MediaPrevTrack, MediaStop).
>
> Note: All key combinations must include either Ctrl* or Alt
> ...